# .net 5 Response returning text and numbers

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working with ASP.net 5 trying to return a text string.

```
response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
                response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With, Session");
                response.ContentType = "application/text";
                response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;                
                await Response.WriteAsync("FAIL");
```

When the return is generated it returns the start point and the length of the string:

```
    0
    FAIL
    4
```

How can I get this to simply only return the string?

##Edit##
Im calling the API from Fiddler. I have other API's created in framework not core and they return exactly what I expect - plain text no extra numbers.

Comment: Where are you seeing the response including numbers? I'd be more inclined to believe that this is the tool you're using that is adding these to the formatted view it gives you, rather than anything to do with the API.

Comment: Sorry I'd forgot to mention Fiddler, text has been edited

Comment: You are correct it is fiddler, if I run it 2-3 one after the other it works but the first one always says its encoded.